# How to fetch all the header details information of all calls (css,js,xhr etc)in a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to fetch all the header details information of all calls (css,js,xhr etc)in a page using jquery.
Fetch all the header detail information of all request in a page rather than xmlhttp request.

Comment: That you can do with server side codes.

Comment: Thanks. but here i need to fetch the data as like our chrome console network did. chrome get all the data information in the network without accessing our server